# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, user-controls, lazy-loading

I'm building my application using `User Controls` so I have Main Form and I display User Controls with this code:

```
        Modules.CtrlListContractors mo = new Modules.CtrlListContractors();
        splitContainerControl.Panel1.Controls.Clear();
        splitContainerControl.Panel1.Controls.Add(mo);
```

and within `User Control` I can put anything with it but my problem about this error message :

`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

I have some relations with my tables that is displayed as `GridView` inside `CtrlListContractors` and when I click the menu button to show `CtrlListContractors` I get the above error message and I think it's because about `Lazy Loading` so it will need to execute more queries to get additional data from related tables.

I have this code to execute at User Control Load event:

```
using (ContractorsEntities context = new ContractorsEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection))
        {
            memberBindingSource.DataSource = context.Members.ToList();
        }
```

I think the problem will be solved if I can get all data from main table and related tables at the same query before ObjectContext get disposed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Error : The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354954/entity-framework-error-the-objectcontext-instance-has-been-disposed-and-can-no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dispose the `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`), you'll have to grab *all* the data you need first. Including the related entities.

That can be done using `Include`, there are two overloads: [`Include(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) and more [strongly typed `Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx) (available from EF 4.1)

So, assuming there's a relationship `Member (0-1) ---- (*) Contractors`, you can `Include` the collection:

```
context.Members.Include(x => x.Contractors).ToList();
```

But as I said, you'd have to include *everything* you need before disposing the context. Either that or don't dispose the context and lazily load the details.

Comment: I don't want to dispose context but after executing the code that will show `CtrlListContractors` it will get disposed automatically

Comment: @SzamDev Well, you should dispose it. And you should be in control *when* that happens. The best possible thing would be to compose a custom query and then map the results to a collection.